# Intellij code formatting, Method name on new line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting

I'm using Intellij IDEA 14.1.4 and trying to achieve this method declaration style:

```
public static Map<Something, Collection<OfSomethingElse>>
someMethod(final Object arg0,
           final int arg1,
           final String something)
throws Exception {
  // ...
}
```

rather than

```
public static Map<Something, Collection<OfSomethingElse>> someMethod(final Object arg0,
                                                                     final int arg1,
                                                                     final String something)
    throws Exception {
  // ...
}
```

On code auto-formatting. is it possible? I can't find such option in java code style window. Please don't tell me I'll have to write a plugin for that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 14.1, IntelliJ IDEA does not have options to either force a line break before the name of a method or to remove the indentation of a 'throws' clause.

Writing a plugin won't help here either, unless you want to replace the entire Java formatter; the plugin API doesn't allow to perform local customizations of individual formatting rules.

Comment: Bad news, but good to know even so. I (too) can stop hunting, then.